# C++ writing a proper function-like macro

Tags: c++, directive

I've been banging my head trying to write a proper `#define` function-like macro but am getting stuck. Here's the example I'm working with:

```
#include <iostream>
#define pMAKE(x,y,z,dest)\
    (dest).(x) = (x);\
    (dest).(y) = (y);\
    (dest).(z) = (z);

struct pt {
    double x, y, z;
};

int main() {
    pt p;
    pMAKE(0,1,2,p);
    return 0;
}
```

And the errors I'm getting:

```
A.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
A.cpp:13: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
A.cpp:13: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
A.cpp:13: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
```

What do the errors mean and why am I getting them? I managed to get the following to work the way I wanted, but I honestly just got lucky and I seriously don't understand what's going on.

```
#define pMAKE(X,Y,Z,dest)\
    dest.x = (X);\
    dest.y = (Y);\
    dest.z = (Z);
```

I appreciate every bit of help!

Comment: Short answer : DON'T WRITE MACROS IN C++.

Comment: Seriously. I'll answer the question (if nobody else is correct first), but why are you going this route? This is what a constructor is for. You don't even need a constructor since it's an aggregate. Just use brace initialization.

Comment: I agree that macro's are a terrible idea. My only reason is that I working on pre-existing code that already has a bunch of these macros implemented for vector calculations (cross product, etc). Since the code's already in place I might as well use it. Unfortunately, it appears I'm having trouble calling these macros in the first place.

Comment: No, don't use it. Use GLM. Use whatever, just don't use macros. It will be faster to refactor than to deal with this crap.

Comment: @BarneyHsiao It's simple to replace function-like macros with inline functions. The macro can't do anything the function can't. This is not a painful band-aid to pull.

Comment: Donno which compiler you are using but try find the option to display de preporcessor output. You will get your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the first version of your macro, `pMAKE(0,1,2,p);` expands to

```
p.0 = 0;
p.1 = 1;
p.2 = 2;;
```

In other words, you've pre-processed away references to the `x`, `y`, `z` members of `pt` by using `x`, `y`, `z` as both variable names (on the left of the assignments) and labels to be replaced by the pre-processor (on the right of the assignments).

(As noted by Konrad Rudolph) Your macro still has another serious error unfortunately.  Consider code of the form

```
pt p;
if (foo)
    pMAKE(0,1,2,p);
```

which expands to

```
pt p;
if (foo)
    p.x = 0;
p.y = 1;  // happens regardless of 'foo' test
p.z = 2;; // happens regardless of 'foo' test
```

You can fix this (and get rid of that annoying extra semi-colon) by changing your macro to

```
#define pMAKE(X,Y,Z,dest)\
    do { \
        (dest).x = (X);\
        (dest).y = (Y);\
        (dest).z = (Z);\
    } while (0)
```

Comment: @JackAidley Because `p.(0)` is nonsense. Undeserved downvote.

Comment: @JackAidley I thought showing how the macro expanded made this obvious.  I've included additional explanation now.

Comment: “not a big deal” – actually kind of a big deal because of this: `if (foo) pMAKE(1, 2, 3, p);` …

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks, can't believe I missed that!  I've updated my answer accordingly

Comment: What? Look closer at the suggested code, the main problem is still there.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Good spot.  I must have updated this just as you posted your comment.  Or do you still see an error in my edited answer?

Comment: @BarneyHsiao Updated again, fixing various copy-paste errors in the macro

Comment: You don't need to use the do/while trick, because in this case, the macro can evaluate to an expression: `#define pMAKE(X,Y,Z,dest) ((dest).x=(X),(dest).y=(Y),(dest).z=(Z),(void)0)`.

Answer (score 6):

```
struct pt {
    double x, y, z;
    pt(double _x, double _y, double _z) : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z) { }
};

pt p (0.0, 1.0, 2.0);
```

Don't use macros in C++.

Or, as @potatoswatter suggested, get it done right at once <strike>in C++11</strike>

```
struct pt { double x, y, z; };
pt p = { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0 };
```

Comment: You still need an `=` operator before C++11. Eh, I'll just edit it for you.

Answer (score 3):

> What do the errors mean and why am I getting them?

The macro replaces *all* occurrences of its parameters with the arguments; so

```
(dest).(x) = (x)
```

becomes

```
(dest).(0) = (0)
```

which is nonsense. The compiler expects a member name (an identifier, referred to as an "unqualified-id" by the language syntax), but sees `(0)` instead.

In the second version, `x` isn't a parameter name, so `dest.x` is not changed.

A better approach would be to avoid macros; use a function:

```
pt make_pt(double x, double y, double z) {
    pt p;
    p.x = x; 
    p.y = y;
    p.z = z;
    return p;
}

int main() {
    pt p = make_pt(0,1,2);
}
```

or just use aggregate initialisation:

```
int main() {
    pt p = {0,1,2};
}
```

and, in C++11, assignment from an initialiser list:

```
p = {4,5,6};
```

Answer (score 2):

Macros work as **textual** replacement. Everywhere a parameter of the macro appears in the replacement list, is is textually replaced by the argument. So in your case, `pMAKE(0, 1, 2, p);` expands to:

```
(p).(0) = (0);
(p).(1) = (1);
(p).(2) = (2);;
```

(Actually, it would be all on one line, since macros don't preserve newlines, but I put it on three lines for clarity).

In your case, you don't want a macro. You want an inline function (probably a member function or constructor of `pt`). Only use macros where you need their textual nature (such as combining tokens into identifiers etc.). For all else, use (inline) functions. Like this:

```
struct pt
{
  double x, y, z;
  pt(double ax, double ay, double az) : x(ax), y(ay), z(az) {}
};

int main()
{
  pt p(0, 1, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an inline function,

```
pt& pMake(int x, int y, int z, pt&p){
    p.x=x;
    p.y=y;
    p.z=z;
    return p;
};
```

Comment: I believe that inline is the correct answer... but where exactly is `inline` in this code? EDIT: I now realize that inline is actually not the correct answer for initialization.

Comment: That's still terrible design.

Comment: @WaleedKhan you seldom need to write `inline`. Compiler will know what to do with it better.

Comment: @Bartek Not sure what motivates this comment. In fact, you explicitly need to write `inline` *quite often* to respect ODR (in fact, you need to for every  header-defined namespace-scope function unless you’re using an unnamed namespace).

Comment: (1) Oops I forgot to put the inline word in. (2) The OP was not using a constructor, and I assumed that the class pt could not be added to because it is usually defined in a library. He defines it here but I thought that was just so that he could ask the question and show the structure.

Answer (score 1):

The `.(x)` member access accidentally uses the name of the parameter `x`. (Also, the second operand of a member access isn't an expression, so the parentheses don't belong.) Best practice is to keep all macro names and macro parameters in all caps, to prevent naming collisions. And avoid single character identifiers, too.

```
#define POINT_MAKE(X,Y,Z,DEST)\
    (DEST).x = (X);\
    (DEST).y = (Y);\
    (DEST).z = (Z);
```